# Looking for examples of ASP.NET MVC applications with the Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Are there any open-source examples of ASP.NET MVC applications that use the Entity Framework?  I have found [Nerd Dinner](http://www.nerddinner.com/) to be helpful but it is using Linq to SQL.

I am trying to use the Entity Framework in a strongly-typed ASP.NET MVC project and am finding that anything beyond the simple tutorial becomes rather difficult to implement.  I am thinking that if I could see some slightly more complex example code, that would help me a great deal.  I am particularly interested in examples that are "real-world" and have to deal with multiple data tables when performing data entry/updates.  Is anyone familiar with a good source for this information?

So far in my experience, I have not used much ASP.NET MVC but have been using the Entity Framework for about 8 months.

Comment: Couldn't you just take the NerdDinner sample, toss out Linq-to-SQL, and use Entity Framework instead? Should be fairly simple to do.

Comment: That's what I've done but I'm looking for more so that I can see more about the intricacies of using EF in MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF team, in conjunction with P&P, are currently in the process of developing an EF (version 4) data access reference implementation that uses ASP.NET MVC as the front-end.

The project will be made available iteratively on CodePlex here:

http://dataguidance.codeplex.com/

We haven't yet made our first source drop but it will be happening within the next couple of weeks.

UPDATE: We have now dropped code - please be advised that it should be considered alpha quality and is subject to change.

Comment: This is definitely what I am looking for, but I must admit it is a bit confusing to try and learn what the source code is doing with a lot of the new features of .NET 4 to which I haven't yet been exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found so far

[ASP.NET MVC Example Application over Northwind with the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/01/29/asp-net-mvc-example-application-over-northwind-with-the-entity-framework.aspx)

[Same article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/02/mvc-framework-example) but possibly newer?

Comment: This is helpful, but I am ideally looking for more complex (i.e. real-world examples).

Answer (score 1):

You might check out MvcCms at http://mvccms.codeplex.com.  It isn't officially released until July but there is source code available.

Comment: Mvc Cms has an official release now.  Only a moth late!

Answer (score 1):

This example: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/44445#DownloadId=121650

This book: http://apress.com/book/view/9781430228868

This walkthrough/blog is fun too: http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront

Answer (score 1):

There is now a 10-tutorial series using Code First; here is a link to the first in the series:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

There's also the MVC Music Store now: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/ that shows MVC2 and EF4.

Answer (score 0):

http://asp.net/mvc has recently been updated with the music store, and the examples now use EF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more complete tutorial with edit/delete http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/AuthorContactManager06102009052732AM/AuthorContactManager.aspx