# Why ASP.NET MVC favorites Linq to SQL over LINQ to Entities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

The question is in the title.

Comment: What leads you to make this assumption?

Comment: Do you mean, why do asp.net MVC DEVELOPERS favor linq to sql?  Even then, I'm not so sure I'd say that.

Comment: All of the examples I have encountered with are using Ling to SQL. (few books and lot of online resources) I had some problems building the site with LINQ to Entities which can be just a consequence of the first argument.

Comment: @Ante see my answer. LINQ to Entities is hard, compared to LINQ to SQL. But it has nothing to do with MVC - it's just a DAL.

Comment: Creating strongly typed views isn't working for me. I'm getting some strange errors when sending data to some views. Well, is there some article good article on migrating from from "ling to sql" to "linq to entities"? Or some good resources on topic Asp.net MVC and LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't favor one over the other at all. It's just common to use LINQ to SQL examples because they are simpler to setup and deploy, so it's easier to digest the sample code without getting distracted by something which deserves its own learning path.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it does not favor one over the other.  I always assumed that Linq to SQL tended to be used in examples because it was released about a year earlier.  Therefore, book writers were more familiar with Linq to SQL and/or felt it was more stable.

I agree with Rex in that it makes more sense, when giving a tutorial about ASP.NET MVC, to keep other technology decisions simple.  Since either DAL implementation can be used, it is easiest to teach MVC by using Linq to SQL (the simpler of the two).  Linq to SQL is also widely considered to be more light-weight.

I must admit, it would be nice to have more open-source examples of projects using ASP.NET MVC along with Entity Framework.  I can tell you that it works fine, because I am using it on one project.  However, it can be a bit more difficult to figure out some of the ideosyncrasies.  [Here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950491/looking-for-examples-of-asp-net-mvc-applications-with-the-entity-framework) that shows some links to examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think this tendency to use the path of least resistance in example is a diservice to new developers. How many times have you seen an example, with the caveat that it is not production worthy code, with no reason as to why it is not appropriate, or good direction on how to find what is best? Personally, I appreciate longer examples that actually lead me to discover how something should be used are more helpful.

In this particular case, using Linq to Entities would be much more useful, as it is seemingly the future.

Comment: Great point, but wouldn't this notion be more appropriate as a comment?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it doesn't favor it.  It's what you see in most examples, because Linq to Sql is the fastest way to get examples up and running.   Rails follows the same convention of many examples using features (scaffolding for example) that you would rarely see used in a production site.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other posters have said - L2S samples are just a lot easier to put together hence you'll see them quoted more.  In reality your MVC models may not use L2S directly - they could be hooking up to a separate services tier or some data transfer objects exposed by another system entirely.